# Why are some of my files being magically added to .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've been having this issue for months now across several repos and several different machines. Here's what typically happens:

1. I create a simple .gitignore file excluding maybe one sub-directory of the root repository and *.txt files.
2. I work on some stuff until it's time to go, so I do a quick `git add .`
   `git commit -m "Add stuff"`
   `git push`
3. Come back later and `git pull`, only to find that some of those files that I'd been working on in Step 2 have been appended to my .gitignore file. It's not an issue if I'm still on the same machine from Step 2, but I bounce around from machine to machine as I'm a student and have to use whatever machine is available in the computer lab at the time.
4. Delete appended lines from the .gitignore.
5. Repeat

This happens with Ubuntu and Windows 7. I feel like I've taken crazy-pills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git blame .gitignore` to see who's been messing with it and when. If it's you, I suggest you `git status` and/or `git diff` before you `git commit`, in case some tool/editor/whatever is being "helpful".

Comment: Well, it's just my Java homework, so nobody else is messing with it. It may be something that NetBeans is doing that I'm not aware of. Thanks.